# How to figure out which wordpress theme a site was using?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I create 20-30 WP sites a year.  Often when I am specing out what the person wants they give me an example site from the internet.  We want "that" but with our look.

I can create "that" but it seems like it would be a lot easier if I had the materials for my house instead of seeing the house and figuring out what materials (plugins, widgets, sliders, code structure, menu structure).

So if I knew the underlying theme I am guessing that front end dev time would be cut in half.

Given that the theme path is renamed - which it is on most big sites - or that the theme has been altered (css names and so forth) - what is the easiest way to get the correct underlying theme?

Comment: Simply you cannot unless they chose to share this info with public. In addition to that, in most cases, a popular/high traffic website never use a commercial theme. They custom develop it based on (or use parent theme) a framework or default theme.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is impossible, and probably pointless as well. It is not enough to know which theme is being used but you will also need to know its configuration and then what about different versions, local changes or even server settings (ok, this probably only in rare cases).

The best way to know what theme is used on a specific site is to ask the owner of the site. If it saves you half development time then you might consider even paying for the info.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark and others pointed out, automatic theme detectors like [SatoriThemeDetector](http://satoristudio.net/what-wordpress-theme/) or [WhatWPThemeIsThat](http://whatwpthemeisthat.com/) will not help if the developer has removed all css file headings and altered the theme folder names.

There's still something you can try in such situation, even though **it's a moonshot of sorts (no guarantee of success) and requires some detective work**:

- Open .css or .js files which are enqueued by the active theme, look
  for pieces of code (or even comments) that are non-generic, and try
  pasting some into Google. If the original theme is an open-source
  theme (e.g. hosted on WordPress.org), there's a chance you will get
  some links to its public repository.
- Look at the HTML code of the website's pages, specifically the names of css classes on common elements - some of them might still contain theme-specific prefixes
- Put together a list of all scripts and stylesheets enqueued by the theme: they might help you at least get an overall picture of the complexity of the theme being used and the additional libraries/plugins it's bundled with, which in turn can help narrow down the search criteria.

Answer (score -1):

Use site like wpthemedetector.com to detect which theme that site is using or visit that site and press ctrl+u to view its source code you will get a theme css file.In the top of the css file there would be comment about theme.

Comment: I like the website but it was 0 for 3.  The problem is most big shops that start their own theme, take an existing theme, and first thing do a copy and replace with the theme name/special conventions.  So the website is just getting the meta info that any decent company would change to point to them.  Obviously I have checked the css.

Comment: downvoted as if the theme path is renamed then there is no way for those sites to detect the theme and you can't learn it from looking at the source

Comment: wpthemedetector.com doesn't work if you do not disclose theme information in `style.css`.